# get particular value from a json data

Tags: jquery, json, node.js

From the below json data how can i get the`address: '172.16.2.18'`

i only want to get `172.16.2.18` from the below josn data.How it is possible?

```
{
    'Local Area Connection': [{
        address: 'fe80::c1c6:e78a:ece:435',
        family: 'IPv6',
        internal: false
    }, {
        address: '172.16.2.18',
        family: 'IPv4',
        internal: false
    }],
    'VMware Network Adapter VMnet1': [{
            address: 'fe80::55d6:5243:74eb:ec58',
            family: 'IPv6',
            internal: false
        }, {
            address: '169.254.236.88',
            family: 'IPv4',
            internal: false
        }
        'VMware Network Adapter VMnet8': [{
                address: 'fe80::a50c:fc9f:921a:7a22',
                family: 'IPv6',
                internal: false
            }, {
                address: '169.254.122.34',
                family: 'IPv4',
                internal: false
            }
            'Loopback Pseudo-Interface 1': [{
                address: '::1',
                family: 'IPv6',
                internal: true
            }, {
                address: '127.0.0.1',
                family: 'IPv4',
                internal: true
            }]
        }
```

Comment: In which language, if I may ask?!

Comment: Json is used in `""(double Quotes)` not in `single('')`

Comment: @kk12391 - *javascript* doesnt care whether you use single or double quotes for strings.

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of syntax errors* in your json data but, once corrected, you can get access to that element using:

```
var address = jsonData["Local Area Connection"][1].address;
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/VBKvZ/

<sub>* The syntax errors were missing closing array and commas (`],`) after each "adapter list"</sub>